# Compiler doesn't find a class I have as maven dependency

Tags: maven, resteasy, dependency-management

I have a code that has a dependency on the `RESTEasy JAX RS Client`

I added it as a dependency to my project like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I can write the code normally, but when I try to compile, I get these errors:

```
java: cannot access javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder
  class file for javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder not found

java: cannot access javax.ws.rs.core.Link
  class file for javax.ws.rs.core.Link not found

java: cannot access javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget
  class file for javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget not found
```

Although I can find these classes normally, I know they are in my maven repo, and if I look them up using my IDE, I can access them, so I know they exist.

I tried changing the dependency scope to `provided` and `compile` just for the sake of testing it out, but with no luck.

Any idea what I might be missing?

**EDIT**

**relevant pom.xml**

```xml
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>my-project-id</artifactId>
<name>MyProject Name</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**class failing to compile**

```java
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyWebTarget;
import my.project.representations.App;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(SERVER_URL);

        String token = "access_token";

        target.register(new BearerTokenFilter(token));

        Admin admin = target.proxy(Admin.class);

        Realm realm = admin.realm("realm_name");

        for (App app : realm.apps().findAll()) {
            System.out.println(app.getName());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How are you compiling?

Comment: I compiled it with the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), and when I saw this error I tried compiling through maven `mvn clean install` which showed the same problem

Comment: The `.pom` please and one source failing source file please, if possible minimal failing example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you want me to post here, could you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: I would like to see the "pom.xml" file, please remove irrelevant stuff and one ".java" file which fails to compile.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is relevant on the pom, but I added examples

Comment: you first reference `<version>3.0.8.Final</version>` then your example references `<version>3.0.6.Final</version>` which is it?

Comment: `3.0.8`, sorry. I changed it to see if it was something in the version, but the error remained unchanged. I fixed my post

Comment: import declarations would have been great

Comment: added the imports, sorry about that

Comment: Cannot reproduce, compiles (after small changes) fine for me. I might need the full project to look further. But thats getting to large for here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You are not including a dependency to what it is complaining about:

This is where the API classes are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Ajavax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder) is your friend!

#### The following isn't correct as well.

You have marked the `resteasy-client.jar` dependency, as well as the others, that you need as `provided` which means it will **not** be included on the classpath when executed or packaged.

Remove the `<scope>` element on all those dependencies, it is most likely not correct.

Review the `<scope>` element documentation and make sure this is what you intend.

Comment: I tried adding `jaxrs-api` and `resteasy-jaxrs` and it worked, which is weird because I thought I didn't have to do that explicitly